# How to get Docker work properly from within the msys2 bash?

Tags: docker, msys2, conemu

Since I prefer using bash (and use git anyway), I tried running `docker run -it ubuntu bash` (after a successful `hello-world`), which unfortunately resulted in a `invalid handle` error. Using `cmd.exe` instead, it works fine.

Comment: Related: https://github.com/docker/toolbox/issues/231, https://forums.docker.com/t/what-happened-to-winpty-functionality-in-bash-git-bash-on-windows/8774

Comment: Neither mintty nor winpty are required to run Docker in ConEmu.

Comment: @Maximus Indeed, and when I simply used msys2's `bash.exe`, it directly worked (aside from a path conversion issue when using volumes). There _was_ some other problem with a messed up `PS1` plus UTF-8 which originally made me use `mintty`, but I didn't reencounter that anymore. And _awesome_ work you did with ConEmu :)

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the problem is my using ConEmu to host `mintty.exe`. Using `mingw64.exe` (or `mintty.exe`) directly instead, the error reads

> the input device is not a TTY.  If you are using mintty, try prefixing the command with 'winpty'

instead and provides the helpful information to prefix `winpty`, which then also works from within ConEmu. Note however that `winpty` also messes up your command line parameters, e.g. `winpty echo yes /no` yields `yes C:/yourmsyspath/no`...